# Play framework support in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I installed IDEA version 15 with the Scala plugin, but Play projects are enabled [only in the Ultimate edition](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/09/17/scala-and-play-2-0-plugin-for-intellij-idea-14-eap-is-out/). I'm new to Scala and Play, any issues if I run Play outside of IDEA? Would Play "hot deploy" any changes I make in scala source code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just open it as an SBT project and it's fine.

Comment: I can't find an SBT plugin what works with version 15

Comment: Play is by definition an SBT project. I have the Scala plugin and I just opened the `build.sbt` file.

Comment: got it -> first install the Scala Plugin in the Community Edition

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works: (1) create a project using play/activator, (2) open IntelliJ and import as SBT project (accept all defaults), (3) run the project in a command line (externally to IntelliJ), (4) edit project source files in IntelliJ - when you update a file, it is automatically compiled (you can see that refreshing the url localhost:9000)

Answer (score 0):

Play works great outside of IntelliJ. I have developed play applications using Sublime Text and Atom. You'll get the errors in the console, or in the web application itself.

There's also a NetBeans plugin now (http://nbpleasureplugin.com), and the official ScalaIDE should also support it (although I've never tried using it).